# Where to set viewport size in wordpress theme genesis

Tags: wordpress

I have the following meta tag in functions.php file under wordpress.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

and custom CSS as:

```
.x-navbar .desktop .x-nav>li>a>span {
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
}

.x-comments-area{
display:none;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width:801px){
.x-navbar {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.x-navbar .desktop .x-nav>li>a>span {
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
}
}
```

I need to change viewport size as google insight says:

> The page content is 389 CSS pixels wide, but the viewport is only 375
>   CSS pixels wide.

I would like to know where I put the changes in genesis theme as I have got the wordpress website for optimization.

Comment: Try http://www.studiopress.com/forums/

Answer (score 2):

```js
function et_add_viewport_meta_2(){
 echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'et_add_viewport_meta_2' );
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add the below code in your functions.php

```
 /** Add Viewport meta tag for mobile browsers */
     add_action( 'genesis_meta', 'add_viewport_meta_tag' );
     function add_viewport_meta_tag() {
     echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>';
     }
```

Comment: No change in result.

Comment: The main issue to set viewport size

Comment: It throughs error: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action()